# JMeter: POST Import Not Working Like In REST Client

Tags: api, rest, jmeter

I'm still somewhat new to JMeter and not a programmer by trade. (I'm typically a BA/QA who happens understands OO programming and taken a few programming courses.) I'm performing **API testing through REST service calls** to/from our multi-tenant database.

I'm attempting to perform **IMPORT** through JMeter and am having difficulty. I'm able to successfully do it through REST clients like Postman and Advanced REST Client, but when I attempt to configure it in JMeter, it fails.

**In Postman**, the configuration is:

[image: Postman Import Config]

This is successful 100% of the time, as shown in the database.

[image: Postman Import Results]

**In JMeter**, I'm trying to replicate the configuration as follows:

*HTTP Header Manager*

[image: JMeter Header Mgr]

*HTTP Request*

[image: JMeter HTTP Request]

For MIME Type, I've tried "application/vnd.ms-excel", "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", and null - all with no success.

I've tried adding additional Header values in various combinations with no success:

- Content-Disposition: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
- Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel

Any thoughts, comments, insight, possible solutions, are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have inconsistencies w.r.t JMeter and browser or other tools the best way to figure out the differences is capturing requests from both JMeter and browser (or other tool) with a sniffer like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/), detect and work around the differences.

In regards to your case, in JMeter:

1. Remove HTTP Header Manager (or at least `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` header)
2. In HTTP Request:

   - **Check** `Use multipart/form-data for POST`
   - MIME Type: `application/vnd.ms-excel`

See [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article for detailed instructions on how to properly simulate file operations in your JMeter test

Comment: Thanks. After removing the multipart/form-data from the header and adding the MIME Type, it's still not working. I believe the issue might be between the "parent" HTTP Header Manager (at the test plan level) containing 'Content-Type: json' and the Thread Group-specific HTTP Header Manager where 'Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel. I notice in the logging the boundary is not getting set. (e.g., `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=P-oTFP1H-Auu7r0eIScXr7Mfg4dq8MgZMp3haR9c`) Instead I'm getting `Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel`. I'll try downloading Wireshark.

Comment: **Update**: The issue is between the "parent" Header Mgr (`Content-Type: application/json`) & the "children" Header Mgrs. 


Toggling off the "parent" Header Mgr, the import works fine. If I toggle the "parent" back on, it fails. 


Is there a best practice where I don't have to specify the contents of the parent Header Mgr. in each thread group to avoid this?

Comment: Got it working. **I had to remove the Header Mgr at the Test Plan level and instead copy it to each Thread Group within the Test Plan**. So instead of having the `Content-Type: application/json` once, I now have it _32 times_ (1 per Thread Group) so the Thread Groups containing Exports and Imports can have separate Header Mgrs that don't collide with any higher-level Thread Group. _Personally, I think this is bad practice_, but I can't get JMeter won't respect the sub-level Header Mgrs over the higher-level one.